# How to fetch attachment files from Outlook REST API?

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-restapi

I wanted to fetch th attachment files from tht Outlook server using the REST API.

The documentation page isnt really clear on this -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#get-attachments

Comment: i also need to get the attachment from outlook rest API's. i'm  getting the id of attachment with Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId; but i need the attachment in binary data for processing.How could i get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the file attachments of a message(email), you should provide the message Id to the api call:

```
$http.get("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/" + email.Id + "/attachments").then(function (response) {...})
```

Let me know if it answers your question or if you need more clarification on a specific thing.